# https for custom domain on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, https, google-apps

I am trying to add https on a custom domain.
I followed this instruction https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl
After I uploaded .cet and .key, I got a problem below:

[image]

I cannot choose any URLs in the grey area.
Should I add URLs first in somewhere? Where is the link/place to add it? I've already tried every link in google app.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map your subdomain to your application first. See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain